# Best way to cache 1.5MB of data at the client side

Tags: javascript, flash, caching, browser

I have a flash application that uses a large set (~1.5MB) of data. This data is likely to stay the same for a long time so I would like to use a caching method. The data should stay cached even if the user closes his browser (and restarts his computer).

At the moment, I'm using javascript files that are dynamically created and contain the data that will be transfered to flash later on. The server checks the `If Modified since` argument and returns a `Not Modified` if possible.

This method has the drawback that I still have to wait for the request to finish - I would like to rely on the old data while everything is set up and check for a new version later on.

**tldr:**
Is there a possibility to store data in a local cache (in the browser or my flash application) so that it isn't deleted when the browser is closed and is available without another request to the server?

Comment: a) Flash Cookies b) DOM Storage c) regular cookies

Comment: @Johannes: I'm talking about ~1,5MB of data. Flash cookies are for smaller amount, right? I added this to my question

Comment: I'm think that your are looking for web storage http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage

Comment: Normal cookies are no option. FOr flash, it depends on what the user has set in flash options. you CAN allow flash to store that much data - not sure what is the default here (I allow no storage at all). I haven't done much with DOM Storage yet, so not sure if that is an option. But I guess that storing THAT mcuh data shouldn't be done anyway browserside...

Comment: @TlmaK0 That's just another word for DOM storage - but yes, that may be an option. I just don't know any details about that technology (other than "it exists")... If you do: what data size are reasonable to store that way?

Comment: @Johannes you are right! I have stored more than 300 records for the same domain without problems

Comment: here is a good document about localStorage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @TlmaK0: I'll have a look at the web storage, this seems very promising! Consider writing this as an answer so I can accept it. Just one more question: I can't access the web storage from flash, right? So I'll have to ensure that transferring the data from JS to flash doesn't block the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [web storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).
I have stored more than 300 records for the same domain without problems in localStorage.
Here is a good document about web storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

I have never used it from flash but I found this at github https://github.com/shoito/as3webstorage